Using Euler's Identity to simplify $\cos(2t + \pi/4) \cdot \cos(2t)$
To verify if $\cos(2t + \pi/4) \cdot \cos(2t)$ simplifies to $\cos(4t + \pi/4)$ using Euler's identity, I converted both cosine functions into their exponential forms respectively, multiplied the two exponents, and then took back the real part of the product.
Here are the steps which I took:

Using Euler's identity, we can express the cosine functions in their exponential form:
$$
   \cos(2t + \pi/4) = \text{Re} \left(e^{i(2t + \pi/4)}\right)
   $$
$$
   \cos(2t) = \text{Re}\left(e^{i(2t)}\right)
   $$

Now, multiply the two expressions:
$$
   = \left({e^{i(2t + \pi/4)}}\right) \cdot \left({e^{i(2t)}}\right)
   $$

Simplify the product:
$$
   = e^{i(4t + \pi/4)}
   $$

Taking the real part back:
$$
   \text{Re} \left(e^{i(4t + \pi/4)}\right) = \cos(4t + \pi/4) 
   $$


But I know this to be false by trig identity for $\cos(A) \cdot \cos(B)$. So where did I go wrong in the process as for solving 2nd-order ODE with sinusoidal input we use this identity to convert into exponents then use its formula and then take back the real part of the solution.

It is false that $\text{Re}\left(z\right)\text{Re}\left(w\right)=\text{Re}\left(zw\right)$, you can easily find many examples: $z=i$, $w=-i$ give us $\text{Re}(z)=\text{Re}(w)=0$ while $\text{Re}(zw)=\text{Re}(i(-i))=\text{Re}(1)=1\neq 0$.

Also, you stated the equalities wrong. It's not $$\text{Re} \left(\cos(2t + \pi/4)\right) = {e^{i(2t + \pi/4)}}$$ it is $$\cos(2t + \pi/4) = \text{Re} \left({e^{i(2t + \pi/4)}}\right)$$

@jjagmath thanks corrected it now

\begin{align}
\cos(2t+\frac{\pi}{4})&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i(2t+\frac{\pi}{4})}+e^{i[-(2t+\frac{\pi}{4})]})\\
\cos(2t)&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i(2t)}+e^{i(-2t)})\\
\cos(2t+\frac{\pi}{4})\cdot \cos(2t) &=\frac{1}{4}(e^{i(4t+\frac{\pi}{4})}+e^{i(\frac{\pi}{4})}+e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{4})}+e^{i[-(4t+\frac{\pi}{4})]})\\ &=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos(4t+\frac{\pi}{4})+\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})\right]
\end{align}

Here's a way to proceed with real parts. Since $\operatorname{Re}(w)$ is real, we can pull it inside $\operatorname{Re}(z)$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re}(z)\operatorname{Re}(w)
&=\operatorname{Re}(z \operatorname{Re}(w))\\
&=\operatorname{Re}\left(z\frac{w+\overline{w}}{2}\right)\\
&=\frac12 \operatorname{Re}(zw)+\frac12 \operatorname{Re}(z\overline{w})
\end{align}
Now take $z=e^{i(2t+\pi/4)}$, $w=e^{2it}$ for the case of interest.

$$\cos(2t + \pi/4) \cdot \cos(2t)$$
$$= \frac{e^{i(2t + \pi/4)} + e^{-i(2t + \pi/4)}}{2} \cdot \frac{e^{i(2t)} + e^{-i(2t)}}{2}$$
$$= \frac{e^{i(2t + \pi/4)}e^{i2t} + e^{i(2t + \pi/4)}e^{-i2t} + e^{-i(2t + \pi/4)}e^{i2t} + e^{-i(2t + \pi/4)}e^{-i2t}}{4}$$
$$= \frac{e^{i4t + i\pi/4} + e^{i\pi/4} + e^{-i\pi/4} + e^{-i4t - i\pi/4}}{4}$$
$$= \frac{e^{i\pi/4}(e^{i4t} + 1) + e^{-i\pi/4}(1 + e^{-i4t})}{4}$$
$$= \frac{(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(\cos(4t) + i \sin(4t) + 1) + (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(1 + \cos(-4t) + i\sin(-4t))}{4}$$
$$= \frac{(\sqrt{2} + i \sqrt{2})(\cos(4t) + i \sin(4t) + 1) + (\sqrt{2} - i \sqrt{2})(1 + \cos(4t) - i\sin(4t))}{8}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{2}\cos(4t) + i\sqrt{2}\sin(4t) + \sqrt{2} + i \sqrt{2}\cos(4t) - \sqrt{2}\sin(4t) + i\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\cos(4t) - i\sqrt{2}\sin(4t) - i \sqrt{2} - i \sqrt{2}\cos(4t) - \sqrt{2}\sin(4t)}{8}$$
$$= \frac{2\sqrt{2}\cos(4t) - 2\sqrt{2}\sin(4t) + 2\sqrt{2}}{8}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{2}(\cos(4t) - \sin(4t) + 1)}{4}$$
